# NGINX config for laravel API backend

Tags: php, angular, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I deployed my angular front end and my laravel backend to an ubuntu VM onto an nginx web server.

Now the front end works fine and is accessible through my URL, however the backend API does not work - I get 404 Errors about it.

here is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my_ip myurl.de www.myurl.de;
    root /var/www/html/dist;
    index index.html;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/prvt.key;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /3rdpartylicenses.txt {
        alias /var/www/html/dist/3rdpartylicenses.txt;
    }

    location /assets {
        alias /var/www/html/dist/assets;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /index.nginx-debian.html {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ^~ /api {
        root /backend/LeagueOf5v5Backend/public;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock; # Adjust the PHP-FPM socket path if needed
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.html;

    # Additional Nginx configuration settings can go here.
}
```

I tried testing it through https://nginx.viraptor.info which returned it tested for the /api prefix.

However using postman and the URL I get the 404 error. But when I am at my local machine and test it with post man through localhost:8000/api/... it works just fine.

Any help appreciated!

EDIT: This is a config file for both angular and laravel in one

Comment: Shouldn't that be /api/index.php?$query_string in your try_files line?

Comment: @symcbean you mean this try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; to this try_files $uri $uri/ api/index.php?$query_string; ?

Comment: @Frevelman I thing, I understand from your virtual host code is you want to call the backend `Laravel` service when you hit `<your-domain>/api`. According to your instruction, your route will be following `<your-domain>/api/api/` if I'm not wrong and you had defined all routes in the `api.php` route file. plz try it I think that will do work for you. As my suggestion and would be a better solution is to run `laravel` service on different port i.e. `8001` etc. so then you will be able to access you laravel service by `<domain>:8001/api`.

Comment: I fail to see what this question has to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

This is my docker compose gninx config:

```
index index.php

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass app:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    gzip_static on;
}
```

Of course, you are using a socket, I am not, so disregard that diffence, but then I think you have a wrong `location /`, you use `/index.html` when it should be like me.

Also see you are using `index index.html`, it should be `index index.php`, because you are serving Laravel.

Comment: sorry for the confusion - this config file is a "dual" one for my angular front end and the laravel back-end. I don't know how to do it in 2 separate files

Answer (score 0):

@Frevelman the thing, I understand from your `virtual host` code is that you want to call the backend `Laravel` service when you hit
`<your-domain>/api`.

According to your instruction, your route will be following `<your-domain>/api/api/` if I'm not wrong and you had defined all routes in the api.php route file.

Plz try it, I think that will do work for you.

> As my suggestion and would be a better solution is to run Laravel service on a different port i.e. 8001 etc. so then you will be able to access your `Laravel` service by `<domain>:8001/api`

##### To run Laravel on Port:

you can write both codes in a single file as you write in the above example.You will need to update your configuration file with it.

```
// For Angular routing

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my_ip myurl.de www.myurl.de;
    root /var/www/html/dist;
    index index.html;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/prvt.key;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /3rdpartylicenses.txt {
        alias /var/www/html/dist/3rdpartylicenses.txt;
    }

    location /assets {
        alias /var/www/html/dist/assets;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /index.nginx-debian.html {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.html;
}


// For Laravel
server {  
    listen 8001 ssl;
    server_name my_ip myurl.de www.myurl.de;
    root /backend/LeagueOf5v5Backend/public;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/prvt.key;
  
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";  
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";  
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";  
  
    index index.html index.htm index.php;  
  
    location /{  
  
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;  
  
        add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 3600;  
        add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Content-Length;  
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers Range;  
    }  
  
  
  
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }  
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }  
  
    access_log off;  
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/<your-domain-name>-error.log error;  
  
    error_page 404 /index.php;  
      
    location ~ \.php$ {  
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }  
  
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {  
        deny all;  
    }  

}
```

By this configuration. You will `myurl.de/` it will serve the `Angular` application and when you hit `myurl.de:8001/` it will serve `Laravel` application's routes in `web.php` and when you hit `myurl.de:8001/api` it will serve Laravel `api.php` routes file.

##### Advantages

1. The same SSL certificate will be used for both applications because the domain/sub-domain for both apps is the same. We are just using port forwarding to redirect requests to Angular or Laravel.
2. When the request comes to `Angular` then php-fpm will not serve it and load on memory will be reduced.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your Nginx configuration is trying to serve both the Angular frontend and the Laravel backend from the same server block. This can lead to configuration conflicts. To resolve this issue, you may split the configuration into separate server blocks, one for the frontend and another for the backend.

You can try below updated configuration.

```
# Server block for the Angular frontend
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myurl.de www.myurl.de;
    root /var/www/html/dist;
    index index.html;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/prvt.key;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /3rdpartylicenses.txt {
        alias /var/www/html/dist/3rdpartylicenses.txt;
    }

    location /assets {
        alias /var/www/html/dist/assets;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /index.nginx-debian.html {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.html;
}

# Server block for the Laravel backend
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.myurl.de; # Change this to your desired subdomain
    root /backend/LeagueOf5v5Backend/public;
    index index.php;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/prvt.key;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock; # Adjust the PHP-FPM socket path if needed
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

- Here frontend is served from myurl.de/www.myurl.de, and backend
  is served from api.myurl.de.
- Make sure to configure DNS to point api.myurl.de to the same server IP address.
- SSL certificates are applied to both server blocks.
- Each server block has its own *root* directive and configuration tailored for its respective application.

Make sure to replace api.myurl.de with your desired subdomain for the Laravel backend and update DNS accordingly. After making these changes, restart Nginx to apply the new configuration:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

looks wrong to me, it's supposed to me

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

also

```
error_page 404 /index.html;
```

makes nginx force the response code into 404, where PHP cannot override it :( replace it with

```
error_page 404 = /index.html;
```

and nginx will no longer force the response code, and it can be whatever PHP wants it to be, eg `http_response_code(200);` for `HTTP 200 OK`

btw using the extension `.html` for php-scripts is an odd choice, php scripts usually go by the extension `.php` - if I was involved with your project, I would change it to `.php`, I would even consider it a security issue, because I don't want my .html files to execute .php scripts if they happen to contain the string `<?php`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is somewhere else not in your nginx.
According to my previous experience there tow reasons for that

1. Probably your server block request for the same server request. You should use a proxy for your angular and if the request is on the server side, and if the request comes from the client side you should correct your request address. If the request comes from a client first check it with Postman and check the log of your server.
2. Sometimes you should change your proxy address from localhost to 127.0.0.1:your port, in angular and Laravel
   Try them all together and individually.
   Do not forget to restart you server every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can still serve both the application with single configuration file. First you need to start your `Angular` service with pm2 for example on 3000 port.

Then you should keep your Laravel package folder as root folder and do proxy setting to point your location to `3000` port.

```
server {
        root /path_to_your_laravel_package/public/;
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;
        server_name your_server_url;


        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        }

        location /api {
                alias /path_to_your_laravel_package/public/;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi.conf;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```